# Pseudo-Dynamic News Section in a static web site

Tags: javascript, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

currently I am rebuilding the static website of my employers and I need to integrate a news section. I am building the site using Bootstrap 3.0 framework.

I want to use the following approach:

Have a JavaScript that reads data from a .txt file with some JSON in it. For Example:

```
{
"newssection": 
 [
  { "news-date":"Nov. 2013" , "news-header":"Some news 1" , "news-content":"Text 1"}, 
  { "news-date":"Jan. 2014" , "news-header":"Some news 2" , "news-content":"Text 2"}, 
  { "news-date":"Dec. 2014" , "news-header":"Some news n" , "news-content":"Text n"}, 
 ]
}
```

Basically I want the JSON data to be parsed and the corresponding div's to be populated in the news section of website. I think jQuery can do, its already in the Bootstrap framework.

So that whenever the news are updated (maybe twice a year) there is no need to touch the HTML but simply replace the .txt file.

And here my problem starts: I am no programmer and have no idea how such a JavaScrip would look like. If anyone has a JavaScrip JSON parser at hand and also some code examples how to populate div id="xyz" with the appropriate news data.

Also, if there is a better solution available, please let me know. CMS is not an option. 
Maybe the easiest way is to integrate the news data within the JavaScript in a .js file, so in that case only the .js file needs to be updated when new news appear. As said, I am no programmer and am open to all suggestions and help.

Thanks in advance!

-Markus

Comment: Browsers can parse JSON on their own.  A better solution though would be to do this server-side or most crawlers won't see your content.  And why is a CMS not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you had the HTML in there you could just do

```
$(function(){
    $("#IdOfWhereToOutPut").load("theFile.txt");
});
```

For JSON

```
$( function () {

    $.getJSON("foo.json", function(data) {
        var str = "";
        $.each( data.newssection, function( key, val ) {
            str += "<h3>" + val["news-header"] + "</h3><p>" + val["news-content"] + "</p>";
       });
    });

});
```

Comment: put the HTML in the textfile is quite the solution... Things can be so simple sometimes. Thanks!